# Serialization of json to content folder

Tags: json, serialization, playn

I've been reading json files from my content folder using the asset manager to fill my levels. Is there a method that I am not aware of that would allow me to also write files into my content folder? I've been using the standard java writer, but it limits my code to a specific platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write files via PlayN APIs. PlayN games can be compiled to JavaScript and deployed in web browsers. There is no HTML5 API that allows you to write arbitrary data to the file system. There are proposed APIs, but they involve popping up "Save as..." dialogs and they are not widely available in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'd give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You can accept the answer, unless you're looking for additional information.